# Hold call until another endpoint answer call and Bridget them

Tags: asterisk

I use ARI to call 2 endpoints and Bridget them.
I want to hold or play media or play MOH call1 until endpoint2 answer call and then Bridget them.

I tried this plan but PlayBack, BackGround, MusicOnHold all of them block the thread until playing is finished and then call endpoint2.

```
exten => 107,1,NoOp() 
same => n,Answer() 
same => n,MusicOnHold(default,10)
#same => n,BackGround(silence/2&hello-world) 
same => n,Dial(Local/***@from_internal_testing,U(default^postAnswer^1)) same => n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you really using ARI (i.e. Asterisk REST API)? I do not see that you are calling Stasis application from the dialplan. However, this operation should be invoked before you hand over the control over your channel to ARI.

All the methods mentioned above are suppored by ARI in the context “Channels”. The related specification is available here: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Channels+REST+API

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do do not require anything like that, just use app_queue

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Building+Queues

If for some reason you still want do all that youself, you can use TIMEOUT(), dial via Local, conference etc.